# Why is status code 415 returned when an uploaded file is missing in a JAX-RS request body?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, http-status-code-415

I am creating a mobile API that accepts some params in headers and a file(optional) in body as multi part. Now when I try to submit with file present, it works just fine, but when the **file is not present in the request it says 415 error**.
below is code request(for submitting I am using Postman in Chrome)

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@HeaderParam("uid") String userId,
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    // save file to disk
    return Response.status(200).entity("Done").build();
}
```

This is a JAX-RS/Jersey based solution taken from MKYONG tutorial. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: The request doesn't have a json, it just have uid in header(uid: U1234) and file is missing from the body(i don't want to attach it, as its optional). Server is Apache Tomcat 7.x. Where do i get the stack trace since it is not reaching any where in my code?

Comment: I think this is what you are asking(if i am correct)http://pastebin.com/Zh6z2dKK

Comment: Let me try @WandMaker method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an overloaded method like below which does not take file details as inputs and not have `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` for it.

As per [JAX-RS documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html), content-type of request, specified through `@Consumes`, plays a role in resolution of overloaded method to be invoked.

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFile(@HeaderParam("uid") String userId) {

    return Response.status(200).entity("Done").build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you... it worked... i even removed the file params from the overload and its working as per my expectation.

Comment: Yea, I was still editing the answer - updated the answer